# Pivot table to get data to be displayed like this?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2

Bit of an SQL newbie here. I have an SQL table which stores data at specific dates for a specific unique identifier.

Example:

```
UniqueIdentifier    someData1   Date1         SomeData2     Date2       SomeData3   Date3
1                   1000        01/01/2017    2000          01/02/2017  2000        01/03/2017
2                   2000        21/01/2017    2500          21/02/2017  3540        21/03/2017
3                   3000        05/01/2017    3000          08/07/2016  3000        12/05/2016
```

I would like to somehow convert the data so it ends up like this:

```
UniqueIdentifier    Data    Date
1                   1000    01/01/2017
1                   2000    01/02/2017
1                   2000    01/03/2017
2                   2000    21/01/2017
2                   2500    21/02/2017
2                   3540    21/03/2017
3                   3000    05/01/2017
3                   3000    08/07/2016
3                   3000    12/05/2016
```

Basically extracting each date and it's corresponding value into a separate line. I'm guessing I need to use some sort of pivot table to do this, but I'm not quite sure exactly how to do it! Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 2):

Using Union

```
select UniqueIdentifier, someData1 as 'Data', Date1 as 'Date' from <yourtable>   
union
select UniqueIdentifier, someData2 as 'Data', Date2 as 'Date' from <yourtable>
union
select UniqueIdentifier, someData3 as 'Data', Date3 as 'Date' from <yourtable>
```

Comment: @RobertQuick Plus 1 just be aware of the differance between UNION and UNION ALL